# Extract a string up to a symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find all `'` symbols in a string and then extract all the characters from the beginning of the string to the first occurrence of `'`. For example: I have `Jon's` and I need to get `Jon`. Could anyone help me?

Comment: @allentranks you can see that from the question tags: [tag:javascript] [tag:jquery]

Comment: Do you need to remove " ' " from the string or get the part before the first " ' "?

What do you expect if your text is "Papa Jon's Pizza Deliver's" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using `split()` method ?

```
var name="Jon's";
var result=name.split("'")[0];
alert(result);
```

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/aJpda/2/

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame: This solution will return from the beginning of the string to the first occurance because it is returning the first element of the array returned by the split function. you may see it in the sample.

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame Thanks. Actually i have another down voter who is hiding and not telling my why he downvoted

Answer (score 3):

```
var text = "Jon's";
text = text.substring(0, text.indexOf("'"));
```

I don't think this is your problem though. What happens if there are 2 ' in your string? what do you really need? If you explain a bit further, I can help.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myString = "Jon's";

myString = myString.slice( 0, myString.indexOf( "'"  ) );
```

Comment: This way `myString` is returning `'s`. He wants to remove this part of the original string

Comment: @MarkLinus, @Shouvik: It will return `Jon`

Comment: @MarkLinus it will return `Jon`  - its exactly the same code as your answer !!!!!!!

Comment: Now it is, sorry. My page wasn't refreshed

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "Jon's";
var pos = str.indexOf("'");
alert(str);
var newStr = str.slice(0,pos===-1 ? str.length : pos);
alert(newStr);​
```

JSFiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vHCfc/1/)

You can also use the `substring` method:

```
var str = "Jon's";
var pos = str.indexOf("'");
alert(str);
var newStr = str.substr(0,pos===-1 ? str.length : pos);
alert(newStr);​
```

Answer (score 0):

below code will give you the text before "'".

```
"Jon's".split("'")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this:

```
function cutString(string, symbol){
    return string.slice( 0, string.indexOf( symbol  ) );
}
```

Hope this help